# How to create a specific X*X size table? (Battleship game) (HTML, CSS, JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an assignment to create a battleship game, with 3x3 - 10x10 grid.
My current idea would be to create a grid with a click of a button, or at least change the current size with a click of a button. However I'm a beginner and its really difficult to find any simple or understandable advice. So I thought I'd ask here explaining my personal situation.

(I pasted the following code pieces into pastebin since some indentation and formatting seems to disappear here. http://pastebin.com/ZL3cWt8U)

I'm trying to recreate this with a JavaScript function.

```
css:

.cell {border-right: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; float: left; width: 30px; height: 30px;}
.row {clear: both; overflow: hidden;}
.table {border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-top: 1px solid #000000;}

HTML:

<div class="table">
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Here is the function I'm trying to work with. I'm using a dropdown menu which has 3x3 - 10x10 values in it. Pressing a button executes the function.

```
function genTable(gridsize) {

var e = '<div class="table"><div class="row"><div class="cell">&nbsp;</div></div></div>'

var value = $("#option").val(); //gets value from button press (between 3-10)
gridsize = value; // this isn't really necessary, oops
for (i = 0; i <= gridsize-1; i++) { //for loop to create the table
    $("#tabel_here").append(e);

}
}
```

Now, this far it just creates a vertical X x 1 table, just a column.
As far as I know, the solution would be to loop this:

```
<div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
```

As much as needed(*gridsize) in between the row div. This is where I'm stuck because I can't seem make it work without breaking the code.

Also, if there are simpler ways to make this happen let me know, this might be a dumb way to solve the problem, but I just started learning html, css and js.

Now I would like to stress, that this will be used to make a battleship game, so it needs to have as much functionality as possible, this is why I considered using divs as they seem to be the most universal and flexible.

Comment: you're creating a table every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
 var createGrid=function(x,y){
     var arrY = new Array(),
      arrX,
            container = $(".table");
     for(var iy=0; iy<y; iy++){
      arrX = new Array();
      for(var ix=0; ix<x; ix++){
       arrX[ix]='<div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>';
      }
      arrY[iy]='<div class="row">'+arrX.join("\r\n")+'</div>';
     }
     container.append(arrY.join("\r\n"));
    };
// call function
    createGrid(10,10);
```

```css
.cell {display:table-cell; 
    border-right: 1px solid #000000; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; 
    width: 30px; height: 30px;
}
.row {
    display:table-row; 
    clear: both; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.table {
    display:table; 
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    display:table;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table"></div>
```

This is easy and flexibile function. With this, you can easy setup grid just changing values.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/te0hs78L/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for :P

Comment: ;) This I write from my head, look my code and learn how you can use arrays for saving and manipulate with data. Few people use this approach and I don't know why becouse arrays is most powerfull and you can manipulate with data easy. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pf4gbm4L/)

```
function drawGrid(cells)
{
    $(".grid").empty();
    for(var i=0 ; i<cells ; i++)
    {
        var row = $("<div class='rowa'></div>");
        for(var j=0 ; j<cells ; j++)
        {
            row.append("<div class='cella'>&nbsp;</div>");
        }
        $(".grid").append(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create functions to repeat the column creation and row creation and update your HTML. something like below.

```js
var TableUtil = {
    repeatString: function(str, times) { 
       return (new Array(times + 1)).join(str);
    },
 createTableString: function(rows, cols){
    var tableString='<div class="table">',
        rowString ='<div class="row">',
        colString ='<div class="cell">&nbsp</div>';
        
    //create single row
    rowString += this.repeatString(colString, cols);
    rowString +='<div>';
        
    
    //repeat n times the rows
    tableString += this.repeatString(rowString, rows);
    
    return tableString;
 }
};
var el = document.getElementById('TableBox');
el.innerHTML=TableUtil.createTableString(10,5);
```

```css
.cell {border-right: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; float: left; width: 30px; height: 30px;}
.row {clear: both; overflow: hidden;}
.table {border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-top: 1px solid #000000;}
```

```html
<div id="TableBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This response is written in pure JavaScript, so there are no dependencies and libraries. The table that is generated is a DOM object, rather than a string value. This makes this code more extensible for future modifications.

The `TableUtil` namespace provides functions for generating a table given row and column counts.

The `ElementUtils` namespace provides functions for looking up style information for a selector.

**Note:** I added styles to the cells to make them look like Battleship cells. If you need the original code, without the extra style, check out the [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/a8148203-b4ed-4b89-a0f8-0165580806c2/view-source).

The example below, generates a 11 row by 11 column table and calculates the width of the table in the process based on the style rules of a `.cell`.

```js
var ElementUtils = {
  computeElementWidth: function(selector) {
    var styleText = this.getStyleText('.cell');
    var ml = this.grabStyle(styleText, 'margin-left');
    var mr = this.grabStyle(styleText, 'margin-right');
    var pl = this.grabStyle(styleText, 'padding-left');
    var pr = this.grabStyle(styleText, 'padding-right');
    if (ml === 0 && mr === 0) {
      var m = this.grabStyle(styleText, 'margin'); ml = m; mr = m;
    }
    if (pl === 0 && pr === 0) {
      var p = this.grabStyle(styleText, 'padding'); pl = p; pr = p;
    }
    var w = this.grabStyle(styleText, 'width');
    return ml + pl + w + pr + mr;
  },
  findCssRule: function(styleText, rule) {
    var searchIndex = styleText.indexOf(rule);
    var endIndex = styleText.indexOf(';', searchIndex);
    var startIndex = searchIndex + rule.length + 1;
    if (startIndex < endIndex && startIndex > -1) {
      return styleText.substring(startIndex, endIndex).trim();
    }
    return undefined;
  },
  grabStyle: function(styleText, rule) {
    var cssRule = this.findCssRule(styleText, rule);
    if (rule) {
      var values = cssRule.split(' ');
      if (values.length > 1) {
        var isMargin = rule === 'margin';
        var isPadding = rule === 'padding';
        if (isMargin || isPadding) {
          if (values[0].indexOf('px') > -1) {
            return this.parseNumber(values[1]);
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (values[0].indexOf('px') > -1) {
          return this.parseNumber(values[0]);
        }
      }
    }
    if (rule.match('width|height|margin|padding|border')) {
        return 0;
    }
    return undefined;
  },
  getStyleText: function(selector) {
    var styleSheets = document.styleSheets[0];
    var classes = styleSheets.rules || styleSheets.cssRules;
    for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
      var curr = classes[x];
      if (curr.selectorText === selector) {
        return curr.cssText ? curr.cssText : curr.style.cssText;
      }
    }
    return '';
  },
  parseNumber: function(value) {
    var match = value.match(/\d+/);
    return match.length > 0 ? parseInt(match[0], 10) : 0;
  }
};

var TableUtil = {
  createTable: function(rows, cols) {
    var tableEl = this.createEl('DIV', 'table');
    for (var row = 0; row < rows + 1; row++) {
      this.createRow(tableEl, row, cols + 1);
    }
    tableEl.style.width = this.calculateTableWidth(cols + 1);
    return tableEl;
  },
  createRow: function(tableEl, row, cols) {
    var rowEl = this.createEl('DIV', 'row');
    for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
      this.createCol(rowEl, row, col);
    }
    tableEl.appendChild(rowEl);
  },
  createCol: function(rowEl, row, col) {
    var isX = col === 0;
    var isY = row === 0;
    var cls = isX || isY ? 'cell-outer' : 'cell-inner';
    var txt = (isX && row > 0 ? String.fromCharCode(64 + row) : isY && col > 0 ? col : '').toString();
    rowEl.appendChild(this.createEl('DIV', 'cell ' + cls, txt));
  },
  createEl: function(tagName, className, innerHTML) {
    var el = document.createElement(tagName);
    el.className = className;
    el.innerHTML = innerHTML || '';
    return el;
  },
  calculateTableWidth: function(cols) {
    var elWidth = ElementUtils.computeElementWidth('.cell');
    return ((elWidth + 1) * cols) + 'px';
  }
};

var el = document.getElementById('TableBox');
el.appendChild(TableUtil.createTable(10, 10));
```

```css
.cell {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  border-right: 1px solid #5C9DC2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5C9DC2;
}
.row {
  clear: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table {
  border-left: 1px solid #5C9DC2;
  border-top: 1px solid #5C9DC2;
}
/** Cell text and background styles. */

.cell-outer {
  background: #3a7ca8;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #071E7A;
  text-shadow: #FFFFFF 0.05em 0.05em 0.1em;
}
.cell-inner {
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#071e7a+0,3eabcd+9,3eabcd+15,3a7ca8+29,6598c0+100 */
  background: #071e7a;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #071e7a 0%, #3eabcd 9%, #3eabcd 15%, #3a7ca8 29%, #6598c0 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #071e7a), color-stop(9%, #3eabcd), color-stop(15%, #3eabcd), color-stop(29%, #3a7ca8), color-stop(100%, #6598c0));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #071e7a 0%, #3eabcd 9%, #3eabcd 15%, #3a7ca8 29%, #6598c0 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #071e7a 0%, #3eabcd 9%, #3eabcd 15%, #3a7ca8 29%, #6598c0 100%);
  /* Opera 12+ */
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #071e7a 0%, #3eabcd 9%, #3eabcd 15%, #3a7ca8 29%, #6598c0 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #071e7a 0%, #3eabcd 9%, #3eabcd 15%, #3a7ca8 29%, #6598c0 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#071e7a', endColorstr='#6598c0', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
.cell-inner:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ff0f13+0,9b3032+14,3eabcd+24,3eabcd+24,3a7ca8+29,3eabcd+55,6598c0+100 */
  background: #ff0f13;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ff0f13 0%, #9b3032 14%, #3eabcd 24%, #3eabcd 24%, #3a7ca8 29%, #3eabcd 55%, #6598c0 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #ff0f13), color-stop(14%, #9b3032), color-stop(24%, #3eabcd), color-stop(24%, #3eabcd), color-stop(29%, #3a7ca8), color-stop(55%, #3eabcd), color-stop(100%, #6598c0));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ff0f13 0%, #9b3032 14%, #3eabcd 24%, #3eabcd 24%, #3a7ca8 29%, #3eabcd 55%, #6598c0 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ff0f13 0%, #9b3032 14%, #3eabcd 24%, #3eabcd 24%, #3a7ca8 29%, #3eabcd 55%, #6598c0 100%);
  /* Opera 12+ */
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ff0f13 0%, #9b3032 14%, #3eabcd 24%, #3eabcd 24%, #3a7ca8 29%, #3eabcd 55%, #6598c0 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #ff0f13 0%, #9b3032 14%, #3eabcd 24%, #3eabcd 24%, #3a7ca8 29%, #3eabcd 55%, #6598c0 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0f13', endColorstr='#6598c0', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

```html
<div id="TableBox"></div>
```